# Emulate Android version older than Lollipop on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to use the Android Studio's AVD Manager to create an emulator. The problem is that the oldest version I can choose is Lollipop (as you can see below). How to install an older version (for example Ice Cream Sandwich) on the virtual device?

[image: system images list]

Comment: you are in recommended tab , just check other tabs (x86 images , other images). 
if you did not installed it, it is in sdk manager , and you should download and install it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider **x86 images** for downloading an older version images like Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that tab. I can see that I can't download and use Android 4.0.4 (IceCreamSandwich) but only 4.0.3 and 4.1. Do you know how to install the 4.0.4 (I need that specific version)?